Top of print has gaps while printing top layers
When printing with 15 % infill everything is printing fine until the top layers.
I used 3 top layers and there where gaps, then I started using 4 top layers but the gaps are still there!
I have an Ender 3 and when I print the files with the Ender 3 it prints perfectly, but with an Ender 3v2 it makes that mess and the Ender 3v2 had a bound extruder upgraded it to a direct drive but it still makes the gaps.

Hi Caleb, welcome to 3D Printing! What do you mean by a "bound extruder", is this the direct drive? When replacing the extruder on the 3v2, did you tune the new extruder?

i didnt tune the direct drive                                                                                                                                              with the bound extruder i mean the extruder with the tube

Have you seen question Gaps in top layer of prints? Please add photos. This appears to be a similar issue, so we'll close this question for being a duplicate.
